# Deleting email addresses where email wasn't sent

Tags: email, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I personally can't see a way to do this, but I'm hoping there could be a clever hack to make it work.

We have to send out regular emails to customers, many of who's emails expire and give us a mail delivery failure. To keep the database accurate and clean, I'd like to delete their record from the database when an email fails to be sent to them.

So currently it goes a little something like this:

```
<cfloop query="rsCustomers">
<cftry>

<cfmail to="rsCustomers.Email" from="us@ourcompany.com" failto="fails@ourcompany.com" subject="Whatever">
[email text here]
</cfmail>

<cfcatch type="any">
<!--- just to skip this record when it fails to send --->
</cfcatch>
</cftry>

</cfloop>
```

I could run a query within the catch area to delete records when there was an error in the record (e.g. malformed email address). But nothing happens when the mail is undeliverable. I get a failure notice to my inbox but these can be in the hundreds so its difficult to manually go through and delete from the database.

Is there anyway to "catch" the failed to send emails and then feed them back in to a query to delete from the database?

Comment: I think this is going to depend heavily on your particular mail server. If there's a hope of doing it in CF, it will almost certainly involve turning off spooling (from the CF admin). Spooling sends things to the mail server asynchronously, so errors do not get reported back to the calling page.

Comment: I don't think you can do it via a try/catch around the `cfmail` tag. I know one of our email services we use will send us an API request for bounced emails, and we can then parse from there. But you're not going to get anything from the cfmail result.

Comment: But, given that failure usually involves sending to the other mail server and waiting for them to bounce it back, you'll probably need to poll your inbox for bounced messages in a separate process.

Comment: You probably want to look at something like MailGun which sends email via an API. That API can then be queried to find bounces etc, which you can use to clean up your database. I believe mailGun may work via SMTP as well, but the API is simple enough to use.

Comment: You will only get an error to catch if there is a problem with the communication between ColdFusion and your mail server. Your mail server will not know an email is non-existent until/unless it receives notification from the mail server for the address to which you are trying to send a message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone once did a presentation on this at a function I attended.  The approach was:

- when sending mail, use a special email address in the failto attribute.
- write a .cfm file that uses the cfpop tag to read mail sent to this address.  (This may have been before the cfexchange tag was available)
- add code that reads Delivery Failure Notfications and extracts the email addresses.
- do something about those addresses

The presenter ran this file as a scheduled job.

Comment: this is really helpful

Answer (score 2):

@Dan Bracuk's answer above is the closest thing to a good answer you're probably going to get.  Here's why: The CF server isn't delivering the mail, per-se. It's just handing the mailpiece off to a real mail server (even if that server runs on the same machine) for delivery. After it's accepted, CF's job is done. Non-delivery at this stage does not reflect on the quality of the address anyway, but rather the connection between your CF server and the mail server.

From there, it's spooled again, by the mail server.  Sometimes a recipient's domain will accept email and ask questions later.  The only way to know if an email delivery has failed is to wait for a Non-Delivery Report (email) to be sent to the failto (if used) or from address. This can come from "your" mail server, or a mail server for the recipient's domain.  Depending on your mail server delivery retry options and third-party delays, this can take a day or more.  If you want to do this yourself, you'll have to write a routine to POP and read the email from the account(s), and analyze them to determine if they are NDRs, and what type.  Non-delivery Reports can indicate hard or soft bounces, blocks, delays, or gateway conditions.  Obviously, many of these are not "throw it out" situations, so you'll have to parse them for SMTP codes http://www.serversmtp.com/en/smtp-error and keywords to determine if you should drop or mark the email address.